# Como validar objetos dentro de objetos com yup/formik?

Tags: javascript, react

Estou utilizando formik com yup para tratar os meus formulários e preciso validar dois objetos que eu setei nos meus valores iniciais do formik:

```
initialValues: {
  company: { company_name: '', cnpj: '', fantasy_name: '', state_registration: '' },
  user: { email: '', password: '' }
},
validationSchema: schema,
```

Esse é meu validation schema yup:

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
    company_name: Yup.string().required('Informe o nome da filial!'),
    cnpj: Yup.string().required('Informe o cnpj!'),
    email: Yup.string().email('Email não possui formato válido').required('Informe o e-mail'),
    password: Yup.string().required('Informe a senha')
  })
```

Eu gostaria de validar as propriedades dentro de user/company, eu tentei algo como:

```
company.company_name: Yup.string().required('Informe o nome da filial!')
```

Porém eu recebo:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta usar `Yup.object().shape()` dentro da propriedade. Algo assim:

```js
import * as Yup from 'yup';

const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  user: Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string()
      .email()
      .required(),
    password: Yup.string().required()
  }),

  company: Yup.object().shape({
    company_name: Yup.string().required(),
    cnpj: Yup.string().required(),
    fantasy_name: Yup.string().required(),
    state_registration: Yup.string().required()
  })
});
```

Veja uma demonstração [aqui](https://codesandbox.io/s/sopt-438234-n9b7z).